# JSF <c:if> with different object type

Tags: jsf, types, jstl, compare, if-statement

I'm trying to compare two different object in JSF.
A String and an Integer, of cours it don't work...

//myVar ==> Integer **object**
//myVar2 ==> String

```
<c:if test="${myVar == myVar2}">
    YES!!!!!!!!
</c:if>
```

I try with myVar.toString but it's wrong.
So how to do it ?

Thank's

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm trying to compare two different object in JSF. A String and an Integer, of cours it don't work...

That does not sound right - I would check the values. For the bean:

```
public class CoercedBean {

  public int getValueAsInt() {
    return 123;
  }

  public String getValueAsString() {
    return "123";
  }

}
```

...these example expressions evaluate to **true**:

```
${coercedBean.valueAsInt == coercedBean.valueAsString}
<h:outputText style="color: blue"
    value="#{coercedBean.valueAsInt eq coercedBean.valueAsString}" />
```

The JSP 2.1 (EL) spec says of evaluating equality:

> ```
> A {==,!=,eq,ne} B
> ```
>
> If A or B is Byte, Short, Character,
>   Integer, or Long coerce both A and B
>   to Long, apply operator

Answer (score 2):

Try using the JSTL fmt tags:

```
<fmt:parseNumber type="number" var="myVar2AsNumber" value=${myVar2} />


<c:if test="${myVar == myVar2AsNumber}">
        YES!!!!!!!!
</c:if>
```

(or, in reverse, you could use fmt:formatNumber to format the Integer as a String and compare to the other string).